# Sum only integers in array (Ruby)

Tags: ruby

I'm attempting to sum only the integers in an array that is passed to my function but keep running up against errors. This is what I have right now.

```
def sum(*x)
    x.each { |i|
        unless i.is_a? Integer
            x.delete_at(x.index(i)) 
        end
    }
    x.inject(:+)
end
```

I don't know the numbers of items that might be in the array as you can see the splat operator. I then loop through each array item and check if it's an integer. If it isn't, it is deleted. Finally after only integers are left, the array is summed.

However, I keep getting the following error.

> No implicit conversion of Fixnum into String (TypeError)

(This error references the line inject is on. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Aside: if you had only integers and strings (without leading digits) , this would work: `x.reduce { |t,e| t+e.to_i }`. Add arrays and hashes (and maybe some other objects) and this would work: `x.reduce { |t,e| t+e.to_s.to_i }`

Comment: Consider using plural names for collections: `x` -> `xs`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a *cute* solution for this :-

```
your_array.grep(Integer).reduce(0, :+)
```

Thus, implement your method as :

```
def sum(*x)
  x.grep(Integer).reduce(0, :+)
end
```

Read [`#grep`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) to understand how it works.

> Returns an array of every element in enum for which Pattern === element. If the optional block is supplied, each matching element is passed to it, and the block’s result is stored in the output array.

Comment: I believe I would have to require something extra to work this though?

Comment: @BorisStitnicky Thank you.. Long weekend.. For me.. :-)

Comment: You might also want to `.reduce( 0, :+ )` for that pesky case where no integers are in the array.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky Valid.. argument.. :-)

Comment: Very nice, @Arup. What would you do without `grep`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland If Ruby stop *grep* service, then I will do as you did in the comment. :-)

Comment: @CarySwoveland: If there is no `grep`, use `select`.

Comment: @tokland, I was referring to Arup's fondness for [Enumerable#grep](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep). I've noticed he's posted many answers that use `grep` in interesting ways, sometimes making use of the fact that it employs `===`.

Answer (score 2):

`x.each` iterates through each index of the array as it was at the time of method application. Suppose you had `x = ["a", "b", "c"]`. In the first iteration over `x.each`, `i` as in your code is `"a"` at index 0. Your code deletes this element from `x`, making it `["b", "c"]`. The iteration goes to index `1`, and `i` is now `"c"` at index 1. Here, the iteration has skipped `"b"`. As a result, the `x` you intended to have checked includes elements that are not integers, and you get the error in doing `inject(:+)`.

Comment: Ahhhh. That makes total sense now!

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple! No need to modify your existing array, just select what you need!

```
irb(main):001:0> a=[1,2,"a",3]
=> [1, 2, "a", 3]

irb(main):002:0> a.select {|ax| ax.is_a? Integer}.reduce(0, :+)
=> 6
```

Comment: haha this is actually pretty close to what I ended up with. I did some more reading up on Ruby and simplified it down. :)